# Flush Static Files Cache button is missing from Magento 2 backend

Tags: magento2, cache

In the Magento 2.2 backend, the Flush Static Files Cache button is not appearing under the Advanced Cache Management
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The clear static files cache button is only available in developer mode.** This can be set using the Magento CLI, with the command `magento deploy:mode:set developer`.

Read more about setting modes here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html

With 2.2.0 there are some differences between developer and production mode. This is one of them.

**Why is it like this?** As pointed out in below github-link, static files are not generated in production mode, hence it doesn't make sense to flush static files cache.

For reference, see this issue on the documentation and the answer:
https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/1482